# How to search unicode string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode

I am searching some simple Cyrillic patterns in strings using python. The pattern I am using is like `/[а-я]+/[а-я]+`. When I search pattern by this code

```
import re
re.search('/[а-я]+/[а-я]+', '/бцршб/бйцбйц')
```

It cannot find anything. But when I write it like this.

```
import re
re.search(u'/[а-я]+/[а-я]+', u'/бцршб/бйцбйц')
```

It works. However in my case, the pattern and text are predefined in Database, so I couldn't find a way to convert them to the Unicode string. What is the solution in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "predefined in storage"? Please post a **complete**, short program that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: @jwodder You can try using `decode()` on strings, it would give you `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` .

Comment: @Anand: actually the behavior you describe is Python 3's where "str"s are already unicode objects.

Comment: Thank you guys. It works when decoding strings. So the code is like:
import re
pattern = '/[а-я]+/[а-я]+'.decode('utf-8')
text = '/йцбйц/бйцбц'.decode('utf-8')
re.search(pattern, text)

Comment: Oh ok , correct, I just tried in Python 2.x , decode() is what the OP needs.

Comment: @Odgiiv: Please post that as an answer. You can answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. It works when decoding strings. So the code is like:

```
import re 
pattern = '/[а-я]+/[а-я]+'.decode('utf-8') 
text = '/йцбйц/бйцбц'.decode('utf-8') 
re.search(pattern, text)
```